# Why wasn't `creat` called `create`?

Tags: history

Was it just to save typing one letter?

I don't think C function names were limited to five characters at the time, as `strcmp` and `unlink` are probably just as old.

I'm hoping someone who was involved said something on the record about this, but I haven't been able to find it.

This is not the same as asking 'What did Ken Thompson mean when he said, “I'd spell create with an 'e'.' because it is a different question with a different answer.

Comment: From Wikiquote: Ken Thompson was once asked what he would do differently if he were redesigning the UNIX system. His reply: "I'd spell creat with an e." http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kenneth_Thompson

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. It says he regrets the decision, it doesn't explain why he made the decision in the first place.

Comment: No, we can link only the duplicates of U & L questions. Not other stack overflow questions. So, the U & L question has the same answer that the other Stack overflow answer also has. So, no issues .

Comment: Oops, didn't even notice that it was the other site.

Answer (score 4):

From [LSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009585) (page 28):

> Yes, this function’s name is missing an "e". Ken Thompson, the creator
> of Unix, once joked that the missing letter was his largest regret in
> the design of Unix.

You should probably look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390979/why-create-system-call-is-called-creat) question.

Comment: This might imply that he doesn't think the reason was very good.  It doesn't explain what the reason was, though.

Comment: Why are you obsessing over such a minor detail? I think this kind of reaction might have been part of his point in telling that joke.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already seen this, and it's not a full answer to your question, but here's a bit from `man 3 creat`:

> ```
> RATIONALE
>        The creat() function is redundant. Its services are also provided by the open() func‐
>        tion. It has been included primarily for  historical  purposes  since  many  existing
>        applications  depend on it. It is best considered a part of the C binding rather than
>        a function that should be provided in other languages.
> ```

Comment: Which part of that rationale explains the misspelling?

Comment: "It has been included primarily for  historical  purposes" explains why the spelling has not changed over time.

Comment: No one expects it to be renamed -- the question is why it was misspelled in the first place.

Comment: That's why I said "It's not a full answer to your question."